# Parcelamento js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Bom criei um  sistema de parcelamento de contas... gostaria de saber como filtrar...

```
[{"tipo":0,"classe":"Saída","nome":"a 1/2","tag":"a","categoria":"Carro","cor":"SkyBlue","data":"2-2016","pg":"1"},{"tipo":0,"classe":"Saída","nome":"a 2/2","tag":"a","categoria":"Carro","cor":"SkyBlue","data":"3-2016","pg":"0"},{"tipo":0,"classe":"Saída","nome":"a2 1/3","tag":"a2","categoria":"Carro","cor":"SkyBlue","data":"2-2016","pg":"0"},{"tipo":0,"classe":"Saída","nome":"a2 2/3","tag":"a2","categoria":"Carro","cor":"SkyBlue","data":"3-2016","pg":"0"},{"tipo":0,"classe":"Saída","nome":"a2 3/3","tag":"a2","categoria":"Carro","cor":"SkyBlue","data":"4-2016","pg":"0"}]
```

essa e a tabela com todos os parcelamentos que estão cadastrado no momento...

por ex. estamos no mes 4-2016 filtrar as atrasadas e a do mês atual apenas... e colocar um aviso de atrasada nas contas atrasadas

Answer (score 1):

```
function checarDatas(data_parcelamento,data_final) {
    var data_1 = new Date(data_parcelamento);
    var data_2 = new Date(data_final);
    if (data_1 < data_2) {
        console.log('atrasada');
    } else if (data_1 > data_2) {
        console.log('adiantada');
    } else {
        console.log('do mes');
    }
}
```

consegui assim :D

Comment: E como estás a chamar essa função?

Comment: checarDatas("13-02-2016","13-03-2016"); em javascript

Comment: Mas esse não é o formato que tens... O JSON tem `"data":"2-2016"`

Comment: sim mais isso e um objeto eu consigo criar ele ali logo abaixo de console.log / esse 2-2016 e a data eu acabei formatando ela corretamente ela estava faltando o dia...

Comment: Ok, `+1`, vou dar uma outra ideia também mais logo.

Comment: blz muda muito o jeito de pensar?

Comment: Estava a pensar em algo como https://jsfiddle.net/twpqq1yo/